# Create a dotted line using msoConnectorType

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an excel macro that currently creates a solid line between two objects. I am using the MsoConnectorStraight (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msoconnectortype?view=office-pia).
How can I create dotted lines ? It is not stated in the microsoft documentation.

Right now I am doing it this way:

```
Set sheetGRAPHE = Sheets("GRAPHE")
sheetGRAPHE.Select
sheetGRAPHE.Cells.Select
sheetGRAPHE.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 100, 100, 100, 100).Name = ConnectID //Produces a straight line
sheetGRAPHE.Shapes(ConnectID).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(250, 0, 0)
sheetGRAPHE.Shapes(ConnectID).Line.Weight = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the DashStyle property of the LineFormat object to msoLineSysDot.

```
sheetGRAPHE.Shapes(ConnectID).Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDot
```

However, your code can be re-written as follows...

```
Dim sheetGRAPHE As Worksheet
Set sheetGRAPHE = Sheets("GRAPHE")

Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = sheetGRAPHE.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 100, 100, 100, 100)

With shp
    .Name = ConnectID
    With .Line
        .DashStyle = msoLineSysDot
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(250, 0, 0)
        .Weight = 1
    End With
End With
```